# Is there a difference between (n==0) and (n==1) as a terminating condition for a factorial function?

Tags: recursion, factorial

I wrote a factorial function and I tried running it with the terminating condition (n==0) and (n==1) and I don't see the any difference, so I was wondering if there is any difference with regard to the performance.

```
int factorial(int n){
   //If condition is changed to n==1 there is no difference.
   if (n == 0){
      return 1;
   }
   return n  * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: The performance difference is pretty much negligible, but if you use `n==1`, you won't be able to calculate `factorial(0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stopping at `n==0` instead of `n==1` would add another step to the calculation, but that's completely negligible.

The main difference is mathematical strictness. If you terminate your calculation with `n==1`, your implementation won't be able to calculate `0!`, which is defined as `1`, according to the convention of an empty product.